# ILP: Exclusive range for variable

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming

In an ILP, How can I write a constraint "X is **not** in the interval [Y, Y+10]" ?

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say, but I'm *assuming* `x` and `y` are non-negative integers and that the range you indicate to avoid is inclusive of endpoints...

You have an "or" condition there, so you will need to introduce a helper or "indicator" variable to handle the *or condition*, call it `z`, and a (constant) parameter for a reasonable upper bound on `y`, call it `M`:

```
z ∈ {0, 1}  # 0 if below y, 1 if above y+10
M > reasonable_upper_bound(y)
```

Then 2 constraints based on that info to *either* constrain x to the lower set of values or the upper, excluding the interval (of disinterest):

```
x <= (y - 1) + z * M
x >= (y + 10 + 1) - (1 - z) * M
```

Truth Table:

```
       z=0      z=1
x <=   y-1      ~M
x >=   ~0       y + 11
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you! These assumptions are indeed correct!